# Added load to thermostat circuit?

Tags: thermostat

I have a couple Nest thermostats that I want to power when my boiler is powered off.

My plan is to hook them up to a 24v transformer using the existing R/W wires (no C wire and I don't want to run one) and just disconnect the wires from the boiler to that.

My question is do I need to add a resistor or some load to the circuit as it will just be going from the transformer, to the nest, and back to the transformer?
[image]

Comment: What are these Nests doing?

Comment: The Nests aren't really doing anything other than logging the temperature and being a clock

Comment: What's controlling the boiler, then? (Also, is this a hydronic or a steam system?)

Comment: During the winter months, the boiler (steam) will be turned on and wired into the Nests - added image to explain

Comment: What the *heck* on the steam boiler is the Nest trying to control? Steam boilers typically aren't connected to *any* sort of thermostat -- instead, there's a vaporstat or pressuretrol on the boiler that controls system pressure, and then there are special thermostatic control valves on the radiators that control local temperatures.

Comment: Sorry, it's a hydronic system - the nest controls the pumps to the different zones.  That's all working fine though, I just need to know if I need to put some sort of load in when it's not connected so the nest doesn't create a short circuit with the transformer.

Comment: A-ha.  Are all of these zones radiator-based, or do some of them have air handlers?  And is this a single family dwelling, or a larger building (multi-family and/or multi-use)?

Comment: They are radiators in a single family, but that's not really relevant as they will not be connected.

Comment: (The radiators vs air handlers question was asked because hydronic air handlers can support cooling as well as heating -- four pipe hydronic using chilled water for cooling and hot water for heating is a common system in modern large-building work)

Comment: Do you already have something that changes over the system from winter operation (hydronic boiler running) to summer operation (hydronic boiler not running), or does the hydronic boiler run year-round?

Comment: There's just a power switch that turns off the boiler (and the power to the thermostat) which is why I want to install a separate transformer that I can swap the thermostat wires to connect to.

Comment: can you provide photos or a diagram of the wiring at the boiler?

Comment: The boiler will not be plugged in, there is only a Red and a White wire that go to the Nest (previously a round manual thermostat). I am disconnecting those wires and connecting them to a transformer as in the picture I added to the end of my question

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this as an actual *switch* and not a mess of manual rewiring :)

Comment: Ah I actually have a plan for that - was just phrasing it as manual rewiring for simplicity. Here is the plan for switching: https://imgur.com/a/fMQJi